# spring validation in composition

Tags: spring, validation, kotlin

I have the following data classes:

```
data class User (
    @field:NotEmpty
    val firstName: String?
    @field:NotEmpty
    val lastName: String?
)

data class Expert (
    @field:NotEmpty
    val name: String?
    @field:NotNull
    val contact: User?
)
```

And I would like to use my rest API endpoint to create an expert with spring validation:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/experts")
class ExpertController(private val expertService: ExpertService) {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    fun create(@Valid @RequestBody dto: Expert) = expertService.create(dto)

}
```

Validation on `name` and `contact` fields works fine. But validation on `firstName` and `lastName` fields (`User` class) doesn't work. Is it a normal behaviour? I can't use validation on composition? Why? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `User` to be validated if it is contained within an `Expert`, you will need to add the `@Valid` annotation to it, so Spring's Validator knows to keep checking, otherwise it will stop.

Try this (untested):

```
data class Expert (
    @field:NotEmpty
    val name: String?

    @field:NotNull
    @field:Valid
    val contact: User?
)
```